# Testing and mocking result of a nested container

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, service-locator

I recently took over a PHP project, which contains little to no tests. This project is fairly large, the classes are mostly quite small, but there is one big issue.

There is a service locator cleverly hidden inside either protected or private variable `DI`, so programmers think they are doing the right thing, which acts as a singleton and is passed pretty much to every single class. A class, which in return uses it to retrieve the dependencies.

Last thursday I created a new team of 3 people, whose new responsibility is to focus solely on testing and its automation, and today finally one of them came to me with the question I feared. A question, I don't know the answer to.

> David, how am I suppose to mock the result of the method which is
>   hidden deeply within the `DI`?

Rewriting the modules to follow DI is unacceptable, we have neither the budget nor the time to do that.

A `do()` method may be called like this?

```
class Baz extends AbstractBaz
{
    public function foo()
    {
        $userProcess = $this->DI->Foo->Bar->FooBar->BarFoo->getUserBar();
        $users = $userProcess->do();

        // work with the $users variable
    }
}
```

The locator itself is huge, you are able to call hundreds of methods by diving deeper and deeper into it.

Is there a way to quickly mock the `Foo->Bar->FooBar->BarFoo->getUserBar` result? The variables are available through the magic `__get` method and hinted by the `@property` annotation.

Using [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/), it would be nice to have something like this:

```
$locator = $this
    ->getMockBuilder('\App\DI\Abstracted\DI')
    ->setMethods(['Foo->Bar->FooBar->BarFoo->getUserBar'])
    ->getMock();

$locator
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('Foo->Bar->FooBar->BarFoo->getUserBar')
    ->will($this->returnValue($desiredObject));
```

Sadly, that does not really work. I am not very skilled with PHPUnit myself. Is there a workaround I haven't found yet?

Comment: Inject a mocked DI instance in the tests, and wire it up to return a mock object when `__get` is called with the value `Foo`. That object you can control perfectly. Also: take a look at [codeception](http://codeception.com). It sits on top of PHPUnit, and makes mocking a lot easier. Also: tell the guy who asked that question that, if testing is more difficult than writing the code, that usually means the code is badly written

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thank you for the comment. The problem, or at least so I think, is the `Foo` returns a container which has, among others, the `Bar` container stored within it. I know I could just start mocking from the bottom (the result of `getUseBar` method) to the main entrance of the `DI`, but that seems wrong and thus I am reluctant to do that. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using multiple (nested) containers, that just feels like a testability nightmare. But what you could do is create a container mock, that returns itself whenever `__get` is called, and returns a mock object from the `getUserBar` method. I'll post a basic example as an answer

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That's actually a really good idea, Elias. Thank you a lot for that. I will fiddle with it for a bit. About the containers, I don't like it either, but I was not responsible for the development and it is too late to change now without writing everything all over again.

Comment: Posted a really basic example, I've not tested it, but I seem to recall that `Stub` worked not too dissimilar to what I've written in my answer, hope it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for PHPUnit earlier, but only just happened to have the time to answer.

Simulating what I wanted is actually possible in PHPUnit, using PHP's [`Closure`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php), which is what anonymous functions in PHP are called.

**Here is a little working PHPUnit example**

```
$classA = $this
    ->getMockBuilder('First\Class\To\Be\Mocked')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods([
        'The',
        'names',
        'of',
        'desired',
        'methods',
    ])
    ->getMock();

$classB = $this
    ->getMockBuilder('Second\Class\To\Be\Mocked')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods([
        'The',
        'names',
        'of',
        'desired',
        'methods',
    ])
    ->getMock();

$serviceLocator = $this
    ->getMockBuilder('Second\Class\To\Be\Mocked')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods([
        '__get',
        'SomeMethod',
    ])
    ->getMock();

$serviceLocator
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('__get')
    ->will($this->returnCallback(function($name) use ($serviceLocator, $classA, $classB)
    {
        switch ($name)
        {
            case 'ClassA':
                return $classA;
            case 'ClassB':
                return $classB;
            default:
                return $serviceLocator;
        }
    }));
```

This code when executed will give the desired returns.

`$serviceLocator->This->That->Them->ClassA` would return the defined `$classA` variable, changing ClassA to ClassB makes the service locator return the `$classB` variable instead.

You can do pretty much anything using callbacks, even simulate return values through reference parameters.

Comment: Looks like a nice approach, BTW: If you find that writing all this code just to run tests is a bit tedious (I know I would), have a look at [codeception's `Stub` component](http://codeception.com/docs/reference/Stub#.VlwasR-v5B0). It sits on top of PHPUnit's mock builder, but offers a more concise, intuitive API

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I had a look at Mockery as well, which seems to do the same thing, but ended up using the default PhpUnit available methods. Anyway, thank you once again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: the people behind `Mockery` are linked to codeception in some way (I don't know who spawned what, but they're linked either way). I just noticed that I already mentioned `Stub` in my original answer... silly. Anyway, doesn't hurt mentioning it twice, IMO, `Stub` is just syntactic sugar on top of PHPUnit, mockery is a bit more, but doesn't always work as expected in my experience...

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in my comments, you *could* stub a container, that returns itself whenever the `__get` method is called, and returns a mocked object from the actual method you're calling in the end. useing [codeception's `Stub` component](http://codeception.com/docs/reference/Stub#.VkoeTB-v5B0), this could look something like:

```
$container = Stub::make(
    'Your\Container',
    [
        'getUserBar' => $returnMock,
    ]
);
Stub::update($container, ['__get' => $container]);//return itself on __get access
```

But as you say: this really is indicative of a more fundamental problem with the code you're trying to test.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because I do not really care whether this specific code works or not, but because I like the approach to solving this problem I have encountered, an approach, which can be replicated by most testing frameworks. Thank you, Elias, once again.